# Why is google autocomplete returning undefined when using getPlace() on the input address

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, directions

Why is google not returning an object with a formatted address when using auto-complete and how can I get a formatted address?

When I log the variable `from_place` it returns an object like so:
[image]

but when I log `to_place` it returns an object with formatted_address:
[image]

I realise I'm using autocomplete on the first form and that's affecting it but how do i get to not affect or give me the formatted address?

```js
// declare variables
var map, infoWindow, placeSearch, autocomplete;

// autocomplete form
var componentForm = {
    locality: "short_name",
    postal_code: "short_name"
};
// autocomplete form

// init google map API's
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 6
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position) {
                var pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                // console.log(pos)
                infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                infoWindow.setContent("Location found.");
                infoWindow.open(map);
                map.setCenter(pos);
            },
            function() {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }
        );
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            document.getElementById("from_places"),
            { types: ["geocode"] }
        );
        var to_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            document.getElementById("to_places")
        );
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, "place_changed", function() {
            // var from_place needs to return an object with a formatted adress
            var from_place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(from_place);
            var from_address = from_place.formatted_address;
            $("#origin").val(from_address);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(to_places, "place_changed", function() {
            var to_place = to_places.getPlace();
            console.log(to_place);
            var to_address = to_place.formatted_address;
            
            $("#destination").val(to_address);
        });
        autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({
            country: ["uk"]
        });
        to_places.setComponentRestrictions({
            country: ["uk"]
        });

        // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
        // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
        autocomplete.setFields(["address_component"]);

        // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
        // address fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress);
    });

    // add all functions related to google in here

    // collection to drop off
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 }
    });
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

    var onChangeHandler = function() {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
    };
    // One destination must be set at anyone time because
    // 70 InvalidValueError: in property destination: must set one of location, placeId or query
    document
        .getElementById("googleAlgorithm2")
        .addEventListener("click", onChangeHandler);

    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
        directionsService.route(
            {
                origin: {
                    query: document.getElementById("from_places").value
                },
                destination: {
                    query: document.getElementById("to_places").value
                },
                travelMode: "DRIVING",
                drivingOptions: {
                    departureTime: new Date(/* now, or future date */),
                    trafficModel: "pessimistic"
                    //    departureTime: new Date(/* now, or future date */),
                }
            },
            function(response, status) {
                if (status === "OK") {
                    directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
                } else {
                    window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
    // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(
        browserHasGeolocation
            ? "Error: The Geolocation service failed"
            : "Error Your browser does not support geolocation."
    );
    infoWindow.open(map);
}

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = "";
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details,
    // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the `formatted_address` returned, you need to specify that field.

Instead of:

```
// Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
// place fields that are returned to just the address components.
autocomplete.setFields(["address_component"]);
```

Do:

```
autocomplete.setFields(["address_component", "formatted_address"]);
```

You are only calling `setFields` on one of your autocomplete inputs.  If you don't call it, you get (and pay for) **all** the fields in the [PlaceResult](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/sfn93x2r/)

[image: screenshot of working autocomplete]

```js
// This sample uses the Autocomplete widget to help the user select a
// place, then it retrieves the address components associated with that
// place, and then it populates the form fields with those details.
// This sample requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script
// src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var placeSearch, autocomplete;

var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
  // geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    document.getElementById('autocomplete'), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
  // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
  autocomplete.setFields(['address_component', 'formatted_address']);

  // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
  // address fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  document.getElementById('formatted_address').innerHTML = "formatted_address:<br>" + place.formatted_address;
  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details,
  // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

</style><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500"><style>#locationField,
#controls {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
}

#autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 99%;
}

.label {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  color: #303030;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}

#address {
  border: 1px solid #000090;
  background-color: #f0f9ff;
  width: 480px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

#address td {
  font-size: 10pt;
}

.field {
  width: 99%;
}

.slimField {
  width: 80px;
}

.wideField {
  width: 200px;
}

#locationField {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="formatted_address"></div>

<!-- Note: The address components in this sample are typical. You might need to adjust them for
           the locations relevant to your app. For more information, see
     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
-->

<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true" /></td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route" disabled="true" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">State</td>
    <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true" /></td>
    <td class="label">Zip code</td>
    <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="country" disabled="true" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```